# Are concurrent database modifications supported in Brightway?

Tags: brightway

I'm trying to run Brightway (Version 2.5) on an application with the intent to support the creation of multiple new activities/exchanges in parallel on the same database (Ecoinvent). Does Brightway support concurrent execution of database modifications?

I tried doing this but I keep getting into errors such as 'database is locked' or 'LockError' (stack trace below).

Stack:

> File "/Users/shantanu/repos/carbontrail-brightway/ef_module.py", line 490, in create_location_specific_activity
> new_activity = original_activity.copy()
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Users/shantanu/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bw2data/project.py", line 446, in writable_project
> return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Users/shantanu/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bw2data/backends/proxies.py", line 446, in copy
> activity.save()
> File "/Users/shantanu/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bw2data/project.py", line 446, in writable_project
> return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Users/shantanu/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bw2data/backends/proxies.py", line 287, in save
> IndexManager(Database(self["database"]).filename).update_dataset(self._data)
> File "/Users/shantanu/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bw2data/search/indices.py", line 50, in update_dataset
> writer = self.get().writer()
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Users/shantanu/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/whoosh/index.py", line 464, in writer
> return SegmentWriter(self, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Users/shantanu/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/whoosh/writing.py", line 515, in **init**
> raise LockError
> whoosh.index.LockError

I'm using a single project across the app and have even tried setting `bd.projects.read_only` to `False`.

Answer (score 1):

The default backend for Brightway is SQLite, which doesn't support concurrent writes, but it isn't difficult to have the writes wait their turn.

The error you are seeing is in the [Whoosh search index](https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). I don't know how you would even be able to do concurrent writes there but I can imagine it could lead to bad things. You can skip the search index with `Database.make_unsearchable()`.

Comment: Thanks for getting back Chris!

So, I dug further into this in the interim and found a few things that might help address the problem. I haven't tried them all but thought I'd first discuss with the community on the approach:

To avoid SQLite lock errors we could:

- Use the 'wal' `journal_mode` in SQLite. This seems like a small enough change to make. [Reference](https://charlesleifer.com/blog/going-fast-with-sqlite-and-python/) - Use `SQLiteQueueDatabase` instead of `SQLiteDatabase` as described [here](https://charlesleifer.com/blog/multi-threaded-sqlite-without-the-operationalerrors)

Comment: To address the issue with whoosh, there seems to be two writers `AsyncWriter` and `BufferedWriter` that were created to address issues around locking: https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/writing.html#whoosh.writing.BufferedWriter. Has this been looked at before?

Comment: Nope. And there is no energy in the core team to look at this, but maybe an opportunity to contribute?

Comment: Me or my team will try contributing to this. Thanks Chris!